# Creating new array out of already existing in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array filled with HTML objects - in my case all of them are **li** items. I have to create new array with textContent from these **lis**. 
So I have two arrays:

```
A = [li, li, li, li, li];
B = [];
```

I've wrote such function:

```
function addContent() {
  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    let newConent = A[i].textContent;
    B.push(newConent);
  }
}
```

So my question is: is there any known method or more optimal way to do that? I'm interested in JavaScript approach.

Thanks in advance (x

Comment: `is there any known method or more optimal way to do that` do what exactly? Could you provide an example with input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

If `A` is an array, you can do it like this:

```js
B = A.map(li => li.textContent)
```

But I don't think you really have an array. If you get elements by method like `querySelectorAll`, you need to make an array for it.

```js
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('li')
const A = []

for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  A.push(lis[i])
}

const B = A.map(li => li.textContent)

console.log(B)
```

```html
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
```

Comment: I'm sure that I have an array, I've checked in console that "proto" indicates that it's an array and "A instanceof Array" indicates the same

Comment: Then you can use `map` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over array of list items and return desired property values:

```js
const list = [...document.querySelectorAll("li")];

const text = list.map(li => li.textContent);

console.log(text);
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, you can also use a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop:

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll("li");
const text = [];

for (item of list)
    text.push(item.textContent);

console.log(text);
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The `map()` method creates a new `array` with the results of calling a provided `function` on every element in the calling array.

```js
let lis = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li'));
let texts = lis.map(li => li.textContent);
console.log(texts);
```

```html
<ul>
<li>First</li>
<li>Second</li>
<li>Third</li>
</ul>
```